# How to filter and print entire row via index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I"m having some issues in trying to print out just the rows based on the `index values`

```
>>>in: print(df)  # My table when I print df

>>>out:
Item          Column1       Column2  Column3   Column4     Column5
Fooooo        64.318        7.574      0.471    0.364      -   
Yooooo        56.839        7.252    (1.914)  (1.945)      (0.015)   
Zaaaaa        45.275        7.186    (7.109)  (1.611)      (0.016)   
Zorrrr         0.381        0.063    (5.305)    (1.6)      (0.017)   
Kaarrr         1.325         0.26    (5.514)  (2.563)      (0.019)
```

**Desired results**

How do I separate the `df` via `index` such that it produces the results below?

```
>>>in: print(df index['Fooooo'])  # For example
>>>out:
Item          Column1       Column2  Column3   Column4     Column5
Fooooo        64.318        7.574      0.471    0.364      -   

>>>in: print(df index['Yooooo'])  # For example
>>>out:
Item          Column1       Column2  Column3   Column4     Column5
Yooooo        56.839        7.252    (1.914)  (1.945)      (0.015)

>>>in: print(df index['Zaaaaa'])  # For example
>>>out:
Item          Column1       Column2  Column3   Column4     Column5  
Zaaaaa        45.275        7.186    (7.109)  (1.611)      (0.016)
```

**I have tried**

`print(df.index[0])` - This just gives me the `Item`. Does not come along with the rest of the `Columns`

Comment: are you looking for this `df.ix['Fooooo']`.

Comment: These method are covered in basic tutorials. Please go through one http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering method:

```
df[df.index == 'Fooooo']

          Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
Item                                            
Fooooo   64.318    7.574   0.471   0.364       -
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
In[31]:df.ix['Fooooo']
Out[31]: 
Column1    64.318
Column2     7.574
Column3     0.471
Column4     0.364
Column5         -
```